# How to permanently delete latest version of S3 Object using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an S3 bucket with versioning enabled. Whenever i make a  [deleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) call using the aws sdk for javascript it will mark the object with a  [delete marker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html). As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property), for deleting s3 object permanently, the "VersionId" should be specified. 
From S3 [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) for making the delete call:

```
var params = {
     Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
     Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
     BypassGovernanceRetention: true || false,
     MFA: 'STRING_VALUE',
     RequestPayer: requester,
     VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
     i.f (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I want to (permanently)delete the latest version of the object. I know that, in order to do so:

- The versions need to be fetched.
- Call "deleteObject" for that version with the "VersionId".

The above approach requires 2 API calls (first for fetching the versions and second for deleting the object version) I have gone through several solutions and they had the same approach as specified above. 
I'm trying to reduce the API calls to one.

- Is there a way where i can specify a place holder for latest version in "VersionId" paramater of the request so that aws will resolve it to the latest version?
- Is there any other way which would require one API call?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You'll need to make the two calls.